# Mounting multipath devices by UUID in fstab

Tags: ubuntu, init.d, fstab, multipath, ocfs2

I have several multipath iSCSI LUN's formatted as `ocfs2` filesystems. They are part of an Ubuntu 14.04 cluster using local heartbeat. This all appears to be working fine if I mount them manually after rebooting.

If I try to automatically mount them by UUID via `fstab` (even with `_netdev` option) I run into issues.

If I have fstab entries (such as the following) commented out during a boot

```
UUID=094c02f6-bfbb-4fe5-8a90-3b6992c81a60     /mnt/lun-1   ocfs2   _netdev        0       0
```

and then uncomment them once logged in and run `mount -a` everything seems fine. i.e. `multipath -ll` shows multiple paths to each iSCSI device. e.g.:

```
3603be8bfce91e3e06e63e5ad426f4d98 dm-5 EQLOGIC ,100E-00
size=15T features='1 queue_if_no_path' hwhandler='0' wp=rw
`-+- policy='round-robin 0' prio=1 status=active
  |- 19:0:0:0 sdr 65:16 active ready  running
  `- 20:0:0:0 sdf 8:80  active ready  running
```

and `mount` shows that `/dev/mapper/*` devices for my iSCSI LUN's:

```
/dev/mapper/3603be8bfce91e3e06e63e5ad426f4d98-part1 on /mnt/lun-1 type ocfs2 (rw,_netdev,heartbeat=local)
```

However, if I then reboot with the same `fstab` entry uncommented, I don't get the same `multipath -ll` output. Namely, only a single multipath device is present, not one for each iSCSI LUN.

`mount` shows the device not as `/dev/mapper/*` but to just a single non-multipath'd device like `/dev/sdc1`.:

```
/dev/sdk1 on /mnt/lun-1 type ocfs2 (rw,_netdev,heartbeat=local)
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is this caused by `multipath` not being fully up-and-running before my `ocfs2` multipath devices are mounted?

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be as I expected, either `multipath` isn't up fully or `open-iscsi` hasn't yet logged into iscsi targets for all paths when the ocfs2 `fstab` entries are mounted. This is despite having `_netdev` as a mount option.

I tried messing around with `init.d` scripts for `/etc/init.d/o2cb` and `/etc/init.d/ocfs2` by adding `iscsi` and `multipath-tools` to their `Should-Start:` and `Should-Stop:` lines. But couldn't seem to get this ocfs2 multipath mounting by UUID to work properly.

If I instead use the relevant multipath device (e.g. `/dev/mapper/3603be8bfce91e3e06e63e5ad426f4d98-part1`) rather than the UUID things boot normally and the mount via `fstab` works correctly using multipath.

The reason I didn't try this initially was that I wanted something to work across multiple hosts which may or may not have multipath. So in the end I have different devices depending on whether I'm on a host with or without multipath. This isn't ideal, but seems to be working.

## `fstab` on Host *with* Multipath

```
/dev/mapper/3603be8bfce91e3e06e63e5ad426f4d98-part1 /mnt/lun-1 ocfs2 _netdev 0 0
```

## `fstab` on Host *without* Multipath

```
/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-3603be8bfce91e3e06e63e5ad426f4d98-part1 /mnt/lun-1 ocfs2 _netdev 0 0
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar problem recently and found this bug:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/multipath-tools/+bug/1547206

So far the work-around of installing the older version and holding it at that version seems to be working. It seems to have resolved all the boot hanging and ordering issues I was having with the current version of the package.

apt-get install multipath-tools=0.4.9-3ubuntu7

apt-mark hold multipath-tools

aptitude hold multipath-tools

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem when trying to mount physical disks in a JBOD that are reachable via two paths. A race between multipath device creation and mounting drives by filesystem UUID happens on every boot. Some devices are mounted using the single path, whereas others use the correct multipath device.

Looking at `/etc/multipath/bindings` I can see that there is a static mapping between the WWID (globally unique drive serial number) and the mpath{a-z} devices. Using filesystem UUIDs to work around non-persistent drive letters was simply not necessary since multipathd implements its own persistent mapping that ensures drive letters do not change across reboots or changes in physical drive attachment.

I cannot say whether this solution applies to iSCSI, but it did work for me for physical multipath devices.